Quadrature formula for polynomials
Peter Lax in his book Linear Algebra and its Applications (2nd Ed.) proves the following quadrature formula as an application of dual vector spaces: given $n$ distinct points $t_{1}, \ldots, t_{n}$ on an interval $[a, b]$, there exist $n$ numbers $m_{1}, \ldots, m_{n}$ such that
$$ \int_{a}^{b} p(t) dt = m_{1}p(t_{1}) + \cdots + m_{n}p(t_{n}) $$
holds for all polynomials $p(t)$ of degree less than $n$.
But, how such quadrature formula can be relevant considering that polynomial integrals are easy to compute? In which cases such a formula is preferable instead of directly computation of the polynomial integral?

Change variables to $b=a+h$, $t_i=a+hc_i$, $m_i=hw_i$. Then what you are looking for in a larger context is a quadrature rule
$$
\int_a^{a+h}f(t)\,dt=h\int_0^1f(a+sh)\,ds=h\,[w_1f(a+c_1h)+...+w_nf(a+c_nh)+O(h^p)]
$$
for any sufficiently smooth $f$.
A general $f$ can be decomposed into its Taylor polynomial of degree $p-1$, usually $p=n$, and a remainder term. If the polynomial part gets evaluated exactly, then the approximation error is solely based on the remainder term. That's the reason for the interest in the exact integration of polynomials up to some degree.
One can brute-force this task by taking any polynomial basis like the monomial one, construct a linear system by evaluating both sides and solve it. Or use a basis based on the nodes $t_i$, like some multiple of the Lagrange interpolation kernel functions, so that one gets direct formulas for the $m_i$.

Thank you! I also found this answer very enlightening.
